# Write app using QuickBooks API to add transaction after credit card sale

Tags: paypal, quickbooks, invoice, vendor

I am exploring the QuickBooks API and am still unclear if my desired outcome is possible. I apologize if something like this was already answered here, but I was unable to find it.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

This whole process except for the credit card swiping should be automatic.
We have 1099 eligible salespersons entered as vendors. I am trying to automate the sales process through a custom mobile app. I can handle the credit card transactions just fine on our server (outside of QuickBooks), but when the transaction comes back complete I want to be able to add the invoice to our QuickBooks online database, then add an entry to pay the Vendor based on the commission percentage of the total amount made.

I know this is possible through an app that presents the user the ability to login with the "blue button", but I would like this whole process automated with no user intervention. Is this even possible? If you need any clarification regarding what I am trying to accomplish I would be happy to clarify.

Thanks for any input. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!